# Order of Eclipse plugin to load a class if two plugins provide different implementation of the same class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

If two different Eclipse plugins (not two versions of the same plugin) provide different implementation of the same Java class then how does an Eclipse application decides which class from which plugin to use? Is there a search/load order of plugins to search for a class implementation?

**EDIT-1**:
This is my use case:

We are using a commercial Eclipse application. This application has a login dialog. the OOTB login dialog, will get the user id and password from user, and try to login when user clicks OK button on the dialog.

In our environment application user id and password are same as user's OS login id. So, I want users to be automatically logged in using application user id and password same as OS login id. The OOTB login dialog does not provide any means of doing this. So, I was thinking if I decompile the OOTB login dialog and add that code to my plugin, in the same package, and change it to auto-login.

I was wondering which login dialog will be called?

Comment: Are you talking about classes defined by extension points or something else? There is no defined order for extension points.

Comment: @greg-449: For classes defined outside the extension points. For example: If I decompile a class from an Eclipse application plugin and implemented it in my plugin in the same package as original class but with bit of changes. Then which class will be loaded - my custom implementation from my plugin or one from the original plugin?

Comment: In the plug-in containing the changed class I think it will get the changes. Other plug-ins that look for a package using `Require-Bundle` won't see the changes. Not sure what happens to plug-ins that use `Import-Package`. This is not a way to replaces exising classes.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449: I added edit to my post to explain my use case.

Comment: No, I don't think that will work. Plug-ins have their own classpaths and won't see your code at all.

Comment: That's my testing showed as well. But I thought there might be a way to specify the order. Thanks a lot! If you could post that as an answer I would mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't override classes in other plug-ins like this.

Each plug-in has a separate classpath and won't see your class at all.

Comment: I wonder, if the use case that I mentioned under "EDIT-1" in my original post would work if I create a fragment project instead of a plugin project?

Comment: Fragments can only override classes in the main plug-in if the plug-in is set up to allow this in the bundle classpath - see [this description](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Steps_to_use_Fragments_to_patch_a_plug-in)